# Showing weights on Tikz graph using "draw edge" commands

Tags: floats, graphs, tkz-graph

I would like to show some numbers as weights of the edges of my Tikz graph. My graph without weights is the following:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, auto, node distance=3cm, ultra thick]
    \tikzstyle{node_style} = [circle,draw=blue,fill=blue!20!,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries]
    \tikzstyle{edge_style} = [draw=black, line width=2, ultra thick]
    \node[node_style] (v1) at (-2,2) {2};
    \node[node_style] (v2) at (2,2) {3};
    \node[node_style] (v3) at (4,0) {6};
    \node[node_style] (v4) at (2,-2) {4};
    \node[node_style] (v5) at (-2,-2) {5};
    \node[node_style] (v6) at (-4,0) {1};
    \draw[edge_style]  (v1) edge (v2);
    \draw[edge_style]  (v2) edge (v3);
    \draw[edge_style]  (v3) edge (v4);
    \draw[edge_style]  (v4) edge (v5);
    \draw[edge_style]  (v5) edge (v6);
    \draw[edge_style]  (v6) edge (v1);
    \draw[edge_style]  (v5) edge (v1);
    \draw[edge_style]  (v5) edge (v2);
    \draw[edge_style]  (v4) edge (v2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

I have tried looking for something on the web, but I have not found anything to show weights using the `\draw` edge command, which is the command I am using in my graph.

Could you suggest me how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To add a label next to an edge, use the syntax `edge node {some text}`. See for example the second tutorial in TikZ's manual, section 3.11 *Adding text next to lines*.

Should you want to place the node on the other side of the line, use `edge node[swap] {some text}`.

Note also that `\tikzstyle` is considered deprecated, you should use `\tikzset` or add the styles to the `tikzpicture` options, as below. See [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372)

Below is three different ways of creating the same graph, one suggested by Alain in the comments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

% first method
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, auto, node distance=3cm, ultra thick,
   node_style/.style={circle,draw=blue,fill=blue!20!,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries},
   edge_style/.style={draw=black, ultra thick}]

    \node[node_style] (v1) at (-2,2) {2};
    \node[node_style] (v2) at (2,2) {3};
    \node[node_style] (v3) at (4,0) {6};
    \node[node_style] (v4) at (2,-2) {4};
    \node[node_style] (v5) at (-2,-2) {5};
    \node[node_style] (v6) at (-4,0) {1};
    \draw[edge_style]  (v1) edge node{1} (v2);
    \draw[edge_style]  (v2) edge node{2} (v3);
    \draw[edge_style]  (v3) edge node{3} (v4);
    \draw[edge_style]  (v4) edge node{4} (v5);
    \draw[edge_style]  (v5) edge node{5} (v6);
    \draw[edge_style]  (v6) edge node{6} (v1);
    \draw[edge_style]  (v5) edge node{7} (v1);
    \draw[edge_style]  (v5) edge node{8} (v2);
    \draw[edge_style]  (v4) edge node{9} (v2);
    \end{tikzpicture}

% Second method
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, auto, node distance=3cm, ultra thick]
   \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,draw=blue,fill=blue!20!,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]
    \node (v1) at (-2,2) {2};
    \node (v2) at (2,2) {3};
    \node (v3) at (4,0) {6};
    \node (v4) at (2,-2) {4};
    \node (v5) at (-2,-2) {5};
    \node (v6) at (-4,0) {1};
   \end{scope}
   \begin{scope}[every edge/.style={draw=black,ultra thick}]
    \draw  (v1) edge node{1} (v2);
    \draw  (v2) edge node{2} (v3);
    \draw  (v3) edge node{3} (v4);
    \draw  (v4) edge node{4} (v5);
    \draw  (v5) edge node{5} (v6);
    \draw  (v6) edge node{6} (v1);
    \draw  (v5) edge node{7} (v1);
    \draw  (v5) edge node{8} (v2);
    \draw  (v4) edge node{9} (v2);
   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

% Third method    
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, auto, node distance=3cm, ultra thick,
   edge_style/.style={draw=black, ultra thick}]

   \foreach [count=\i] \x/\y/\t in {-2/2/2, 2/2/3, 4/0/6, 2/-2/4, -2/-2/5, -4/0/1}
     \node [circle,draw=blue,fill=blue!20!,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries]
        (v\i) at (\x,\y) {\t};

   \foreach \i/\j/\t in {1/2/1, 2/3/2, 3/4/3, 4/5/4, 5/6/5, 6/1/6, 5/1/7, 5/2/8, 4/2/9}
    \draw [edge_style]  (v\i) edge node{\t} (v\j);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In `edge_style/.style={draw=black, line width=2, ultra thick}` the option `line width=2` is overwritten by `ultra thick`, so you can safely remove the former.

Comment: Possible : `\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,draw=blue,fill=blue!20!,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]
   \path    (-2,2) node   (v1) {2} ... ` and `\begin{scope}[every edge/.style={draw=black, ultra thick}]
    \draw  (v1) edge node{1} (v2); ...` to avoid some repetitions ..

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks, will edit. I didn't really look at the styles.

Comment: Had difficulty replicating in my project, so it's important to note that `auto` is required for this to work.